# How to incorporate WebSockets into a Cocoa application

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, websocket

I am developing a Cocoa application which involves a chat element. One approach I've considered is using Websockets to handle client-server communication. This would be particularly desirable because chats will also be displayed on a website, and using Websockets could make the implementation very simple.

So: would it be possible to use a WebView element, and use Websockets within it? (I know Safari doesn't support Websockets yet, so I imagine this is not possible?)

Failing that, are there any Websocket client libraries for C, Objective C, or any other language I could successfully embed within my application?

Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation of websockets for objective-c

http://github.com/esad/zimt

Comment: As of November 2012, [zimt has been deprecated by its author](https://github.com/esad/zimt/commit/39665286bf80dfcc38839870430b2a4350a8f39a) in favor of [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket). Please use that instead of zimt.

Comment: What JeremyW.Sherman said. Also the "accepted" flag should should be removed from this flag and added to mikelikespie's one.

Answer (score 18):

The only objective-c WebSocket library that supports the latest standard, [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (at the time of writing this post) is [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) (disclaimer: I'm author of it).

Both Unitt's and Zimt's client implementations are using deprecated protocols and don't seem to be maintained.

Comment: What about [CoreWebSocket](https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket)? It has a good name and seems fast since it has a C API. I created an issue [CoreWebSocket Vs. SocketRocket](https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket/issues/5) before I saw this.

Answer (score 0):

zimt doesn't seem to work on iOS4 - no changes were made since april 2nd 2010..

Answer (score 0):

There is [libwebsocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-websocket-server-library/4809124#4809124) provided by warmcat as an answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-websocket-server-library) of a C++ Websocket library.

It supports the most recent -04 and -05 standard recommendation and also provides encryption through SSL.
Additionally it should work on iOS devices.

You can use it if you don't mind using C code or you could write an Objective-C wrapper for the library.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get zimt or UnitT to work in my project, so i wrote this quick wrapper around uiwebview to use the native WebSockets supported included in iOS 4.2.

https://github.com/zootreeves/iOS-WebSockets/

Performance is sufficient for small messages.

Comment: What issues did you run into using UnitT? I am happy to fix any problems.

Comment: Josh, I built UnitT and imported the libUnittWebSocketClient.a into my project. Then to test socket = [[WebSocket alloc] initWithURLString:@"ws://ip:8080/" delegate:self origin:nil protocols:nil tlsSettings:nil verifyAccept:NO]; [socket open]; I get the error Open Error Domain=WebSocketErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad handshake" UserInfo=0x16c480 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Bad handshake} the websockets server is Jetty 8. This is on iOS 4.2.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You want the URL to point to your WebSocketServlet. I checked in the project, testws, that I used to run unit test in the library against Jetty 8.0.M2. My websocket pointed to the url, ws://<ip>:8080/testws/ws/test. My web.xml has the following fragment: `
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestWS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.unitt.testws.TestWebSocketServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestWS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`. Does that fix the problem?