# WebSockets client for Objective-C (preferably iOS compatible)

Tags: iphone, ios4, websocket

Closest thing I've found is [How to incorporate WebSockets into a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664002/how-to-incorporate-websockets-into-a-cocoa-application), but the answers only pointed to an outdated library.

Does anyone know about a WebSockets library compatible with iOS 4.x?

I've also read about [Pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com/), and, as good as the service could be, I would prefer to use my own WebSockets server.

Comment: Any new reliable web socket client for iOS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check out the [UnitT Web Socket Client](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient). It is intended for use in iOS apps using Objective-C. It works with both ws & wss.

I am the author and have been using it in some of my projects with success. Let me know if you run into any trouble and I will do what I can to help.

Comment: thanks, I'll be sure to check it out. I'll take this as the answer since it looks very complete.

Comment: Hi Josh, have a problem with your lib. Followed all the steps as in tutorial for this project, but smth is wrong. I get pretty much simiilair errors: `Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused`. Tried both 0.9.5 and 0.9.4 versions, but still cannot fix it, any suggestions.

Here is my test project https://github.com/artem888/WebSocketTest

Comment: What server are you running? I looked through your project but didn't see any code for the web socket. Sorry for the late reply, but my daughter was just born and is finally sleeping through the night.

Comment: Can I use this in XMPPFramework to replace GCDAsyncWebSocket?

Answer (score 8):

Found this post in a google search for iOS WebSockets and wanted to put an updated answer.

Anyways, Zimt and Unitt's client don't support the latest standard (at the time of writing this).

(disclaimer: author of SocketRocket)

We just released a new library that has no external dependencies, supports [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) completely, and works with iOS 4.x+.

It's called [SocketRocket and can be found here](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket)

Comment: Any chance to share the experience/thoughts behind "Delegate-based. Had older versions that could use blocks too, but I felt it didn't blend well with retain cycles and just objective C in general."? say, through a blog or wiki.

Comment: What about [CoreWebSocket Vs. SocketRocket](https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket/issues/5)?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a web application using one of several Cocoa-like libraries and then convert it to a native app using something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)/[Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/).

- [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) - Make webapps using Objective-J and Cocoa-like API.
- [WebSockets for Cappuccino](https://github.com/samsonjs/cpwebsocket)
- [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) - Apple's [Cocoa for the web](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/08/06/16/apples_open_secret_sproutcore_is_cocoa_for_the_web.html)
- [Toth](https://github.com/mauritslamers/Thoth) - a multi-user SproutCore library that uses WebSockets.

For the server side there are lots of options. Just search for ["websockets server"](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=&q=websockets+server&repo=&langOverride=&x=21&y=21&start_value=1) on github.com.

Comment: Nice links. I'll check them out. Thanks. ;)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, it's considered good form to comment on why you downvoted (e.g. quality issues, incorrect information, doesn't answer the question, etc). This provides information to future viewers about why the answer may not be good and also gives the answer author an opportunity to cleanup/fix/learn and improves the overall quality of SO question/answers.

Comment: Unhelpful, offtopic to the question as stated.

Comment: @Justicle, you could argue it's offtopic (although I consider alternative approaches ontopic if they are clearly labelled which it is). But "unhelpful"? The question submitter found them helpful.

Comment: @kanaka - It's unhelpful because I'm also looking for information about WebSockets on iOS, and your answer is an opinion that has nothing to add. It is offtopic - question is tagged as "iphone ios4 websockets" not "alternative approaches to app development".

Comment: @Justicle, my answer is about developing applications that use WebSockets on iOS (and specifically iOS 4.2 and up which supports WebSockets). Ian is/was developing an Cocoa app and wanted to integrate WebSocket support. He may not have been aware that you can develop Cocoa like apps without Objective-C and get WebSockets with it, so I provided some information on that. It very much fits the general gist of the question. If I were in the same situation, I would want to know this alternate approach to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I added an update to note that you can create "native" applications from web applications using PhoneGap/Cordova for those that aren't aware.

Answer (score 0):

I created a package for iOS/Objective-C and TLS taking into account the new iOS13 TLS restrictions. It works with a NodeJS TLS server how I use it. Hope it helps, feel free to contribute.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets