# Using websockets as a web service for iPhone app data?

Tags: iphone, web-services, cocoa-touch, html, websocket

I would like my iPhone app to get and post data via a websockets web service. Is this possible on the iOS SDK? Do you recommend a server web app API?

Answer (score 0):

See this other answer: [WebSockets client for Objective-C (preferably iOS compatible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501121/websockets-client-for-objective-c-preferrably-ios-compatible)