# Ho to update Table View, when My SQL DB is updated with messages?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in iOS Development. I am working on a project to send and receive messages from  MY SQL DB using Rest API.

When App is Open, If User A sends message to User B. How B would know, he has received some messages from A.

I came to know about two things-

1. NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest with ARC
2. beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Could any one help me, how user B would be getting messages from Data Base from above methods.

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501121/websockets-client-for-objective-c-preferrably-ios-compatible

Comment: If you are new to iOS development and want to build a chat application then I would suggest you to read about Push Notifications and XMPP Protocol.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman i m using Web Service and How could i do with it. i was not aware of XMPP