# Mobile Chat Backend Play Framework vs Netty

Tags: mobile, playframework, netty

I want to develop mobile chat backend for android and ios clients. I have experience in playframework 2 with java. Do I need to learn and use netty framework for chat backend? Playframework is also a nio framework running on netty. I can not decide which one to choose? Will be playframework enough for high traffic mobile chat backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play framework should be enough. No need to touch the bare metal (Netty) unless your doing something very complicated (special protocols, etc.). For your use case, you probably just need to familiarize  yourself with the [WebSocket Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and specifically [how to set them up in play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWebSockets).

Your next step would be to setup the clients for android and ios. For android you could take a look at [Java-Websockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) and while im not familiar with iOS, a google search returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501121/websockets-client-for-objective-c-preferrably-ios-compatible) which might be somewhere to start.

All that being said if you'd like to avoid the extra fluff that play provides (sessions, cookies, templates, routing, asset managment, Akka, etc.) and you dont think you will ever need them, then definitely go with Netty if time to learn is a non-issue. Note that with Netty the client libraries above would still apply if you use the same Websocket protocol.

Comment: Clear explanation. Thx!