# Objective-C/C websocket client with full specification support

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, websocket

Yes, I am aware of [How to incorporate WebSockets into a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664002/how-to-incorporate-websockets-into-a-cocoa-application), but that question is almost a year old and it is clear that the selected answer (zimt) is no longer an acceptable solution.

Is there any WebSocket client that is usable from within my iOS application? It can be C or Objective-C, but it has to have full support for WebSocket (Zimt doesn't handle Sec-WebSocket-Key1 and Sec-WebSocket-Key2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket).  It supports the latest standard, [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), which Unitt does not.  No CocoaAsyncSocket dependencies either.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the [UnitT Web Socket Client](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient). It is intended for use in iOS apps using Objective-C. However, Sec-WebSocket-Key1 & Sec-WebSocket-Key2 are part of an earlier revision of web sockets. Since version 6, the client now needs to support Sec-WebSocket-Accept. Unfortunately, not all the servers use this yet. UnitT Web Socket Client allows you turn this check on or off programmatically. In addition, it works with both ws & wss.

I am the author and have been using it in some of my projects with success. Let me know if you run into any trouble and I will do what I can to help.

Comment: Very cool Josh! I may have to patch it though so that it works with Sec-WebSocket-Key* for now because it needs to maintain compatibility with the server. I'll get back to you if I ever actually finish that task.

Comment: Thank you, this is really well done. When checking out the sources, its missing : GCDAsyncSocket.h !

Answer (score 0):

I created an Obj-C package to handle TLS taking into account the latest (iOS 13) TLS restrictions on certificates.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets