# Would Apple allow a PhoneGap app to use websockets in the background?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, websocket

Since it would be such low overhead, would apple allow a PhoneGap app to run in the background and persist communication via websockets?

Comment: You may want to look at this, at least for websockets on iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664002/how-to-incorporate-websockets-into-a-cocoa-application