# Cocoa Websocket Server on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, websocket

I'm porting my application from Windows to Mac using XCode. One thing my application does is it runs a WebSocket server for communication.

I've seen many WebSocket client libraries on github, but I'm having trouble finding one that handles server communication.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is not a duplicate of:
[How to incorporate WebSockets into a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664002/how-to-incorporate-websockets-into-a-cocoa-application)

That library is for the client side, I need something that handles the server side. Also my question is about developing a Mac OSX application, not an iOS application.

I would prefer this to be a Objective-C solution, my application has many other requirements.

Comment: I appreciate everyones answer, but I decided to use Node.js.

Comment: You said you did it from the mac OS application?

Comment: Correct, using NW.js! http://nwjs.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote: https://github.com/mxcl/MBWebSocketServer

Might be useful for you.

Comment: I ended up going with https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit for this project, but I'm still very interested in this. Honestly I'd love to get this working on an iPhone.